# Connect I2C Oled via USB to Linux Box

Tags: usb

I connected a **1.3" SH1106 Oled** via the I2C pins to a i2c-to-usb adapter (**UMFT201XB** from FTDI) and on my Linux Box (Z83 mini pc with Ubuntu 18.04) I can see the device under /dev/ttyUSB0.

This is the dmesg output:

```
[16123.056915] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[16123.212789] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6015
[16123.212806] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[16123.212816] usb 1-2: Product: UMFT201XB
[16123.212825] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[16123.212834] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: FTWCN8T5
[16123.216185] ftdi_sio 1-2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[16123.216361] usb 1-2: Detected FT-X
[16123.216947] usb 1-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Now I want to write text/graphics to the OLED screen but I cannot find the i2c device with `i2cdetect -l`. After plugging in the USB, I don't see a extra device there (maybe there should not even be one?).

I use the `luma.oled` library on the Linux Box, but for the initialization, I need the i2c port and i2c address (somewhere in the docs they mention 0x22, but what port?).

**How can I find the port for the USB adapter**, if there is even one. I am a complete noob with i2c and virtual serial ports, so maybe my approach is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

User `justme` from electronics stackexchange found the answer to my problem:

That is a completely wrong chip for that job. It literally is an I2C to USB adapter, enabling USB via I2C bus. What you need USB to I2C adapter, which enables I2C via USB. FT201 is not a chip to be an I2C master to control slave I2C devices from PC. To the PC this chip looks like an USB serial port, and is an I2C slave chip to some other master device. This chip enables an a I2C master like a microcontroller, which otherwise has no USB connectivity, to communicate with a PC.